# A weather station recorded the temperature every 10 minutes

Tags: probability

I need your help to understand this homework.

A weather station recorded every 10 minutes the temperature. X  is the minimum and Y the maximum temperature in a day. between the 1st and 30th April the values of  X are in [0,15]  and  the Y are in [10,30] 
1) draw the sample space and the following contingencies
A={temperature during the day does not exceed 25 degrees}  B={maximum temperature of the day is at least twice the minimum} C={the difference in maximum & minimum temperatures of day does not exceed 5 degrees}
3) Are the contingents A and C independent?

My basic problem is that i can’t understand who is the sample space and the A, B and C, i am very confused. At first i think that the sample space is Ω={0≤x≤15, 10≤y≤30} and  A={y≤25},  B={y≥2x}, C={(y-x)≤5}  but I am sure that isn’t right.

Comment: Are you sure you mean "prices"? If so, you'll need to explain more about those. Perhaps you mean "values"?

Comment: RAARGH! Unless the temperatures are absolute temperatures (highly unlikely for the given values), you _don't ever speak about twice any temperature!_ (Not your fault, @alex, just an insane problem).

Comment: i thing that says the prices that takes the X are found in the interval....and 1 note that i forget about the exercises also says tht the observation of prices X and Y in one random day of April is an experiment

Comment: @alex, doesn't really help. Perhaps a language problem? In English, "price" is the amount of money you need to pay to buy something. It is not clear at all what that has to do with temperatures and weather stations.

Comment: You can edit the question using the "edit" link underneath it. Then people don't have to read through all the comments to understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you've done so far is correct, although I would write it a little bit differently: $$\Omega=\lbrace(x,y):0\le x\le15,10\le y\le30\rbrace$$ $$A=\lbrace(x,y){\rm\ in\ }\Omega:y\le25\rbrace,\quad B=\lbrace(x,y){\rm\ in\ }\Omega:y\ge2x\rbrace,\quad C=\lbrace(x,y){\rm\ in\ }\Omega:y-x\le5\rbrace$$